# Using SQL to select data from last week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dateadd

What is the best way to select data from the previous week? The below returns a syntax error. 
    SELECT 
    COUNT(dbo.Calls.kbpCallID) NoofoutboundCalls
    FROM (((dbo.Calls LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OrganizationContacts ON dbo.Calls.kbpOrganizationID = dbo.OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID AND dbo.Calls.KbplocationID = dbo.OrganizationContacts.cmclocationID AND dbo.Calls.kbpcontactid = dbo.OrganizationContacts.cmccontactid) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OrganizationLocations ON dbo.OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID = dbo.OrganizationLocations.cmlOrganizationID AND dbo.OrganizationContacts.cmclocationId = dbo.OrganizationLocations.cmllocationid AND dbo.OrganizationContacts.cmccontactid = dbo.organizationlocations.cmlapinvoicecontactid) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Organizations ON dbo.Calls.kbpOrganizationID = dbo.Organizations.cmoOrganizationID) * *
    WHERE dbo.Calls.kbpOpenedDate = DATEADD(week, - 1,) * * AND (dbo.Organizations.cmoCustomerStatus = 1 OR dbo.Organizations.cmoCustomerStatus = 2) AND dbo.Calls.kbpCallTypeID = 'SALOB'

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't completed the syntax for the `DATEADD` function.

`DATEADD` requires 3 parameters:

1. The grain of the function - in your case WEEK
2. The number of intervals - in your case -1
3. The column that you are interacting on - in your case this is missing

As it seems to be based on the current date then I think you want that line to be:

```
`WHERE dbo.Calls.kbpOpenedDate = DATEADD(week, -1, GETDATE())`
```

However, that also is a specific date and time that you are looking for equality on. More likely you are looking for a range so you may have to use greater than instead of equals or include another `DATEADD` to define the start/end range along with this one.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME= DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()-7), CAST(GETDATE()-7 AS DATE))
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME= DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()-7), CAST(GETDATE()-7 AS DATE)) 

SELECT
COUNT(dbo.Calls.kbpCallID) NoofoutboundCalls
FROM (((dbo.Calls 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OrganizationContacts ON dbo.Calls.kbpOrganizationID = dbo.OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID and dbo.Calls.KbplocationID = dbo.OrganizationContacts.cmclocationID and dbo.Calls.kbpcontactid = dbo.OrganizationContacts.cmccontactid) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OrganizationLocations ON dbo.OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID = dbo.OrganizationLocations.cmlOrganizationID and dbo.OrganizationContacts.cmclocationId = dbo.OrganizationLocations.cmllocationid and dbo.OrganizationContacts.cmccontactid = dbo.organizationlocations.cmlapinvoicecontactid) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Organizations ON dbo.Calls.kbpOrganizationID = dbo.Organizations.cmoOrganizationID)    
**WHERE  dbo.Calls.kbpOpenedDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate** 
AND (dbo.Organizations.cmoCustomerStatus  =  1 OR dbo.Organizations.cmoCustomerStatus  =  2) 
AND dbo.Calls.kbpCallTypeID  =  'SALOB'
```